# Convert SQL query to LINQ to Entities

Tags: sql-server, linq

I have a particular scenario where I wrote my code using LINQ-SQL but I would do it ... but the problem is that I can not convert it! Can anyone give me a hand? thanks

Here is the query

**INSERT**

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
USE tempdb;
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.Employe (
  Id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  Name varchar(10) NOT NULL
  );
CREATE TABLE dbo.Customer (
  Id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  Name varchar(10) NOT NULL
  );
CREATE TABLE dbo.Movement (
  Id int NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  EmployeeId int NOT NULL,
  CustomerId int NOT NULL,
  Data date NOT NULL,
  Time int NOT NULL,
  SpecialCost decimal(18,4) NULL
  );
CREATE TABLE dbo.EmployeeCost (
  EmployeeId int NOT NULL,
  Data date NOT NULL,
  Value decimal(18,4) NOT NULL
  );
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.Customer
  VALUES ( 1, 'Cli1' ), ( 2, 'Cli2' ), ( 3, 'Cli3' );
INSERT INTO dbo.Employe
  VALUES ( 1, 'Mirko' ), ( 2, 'Andrea' );
INSERT INTO dbo.EmployeeCost
  VALUES ( 1, '20110101', 1 ), ( 1, '20110701', 1.5 ), ( 1, '20120101', 2 );

INSERT INTO dbo.EmployeeCost
  VALUES ( 2, '20110101', 1 ), ( 2, '20120101', 1.3 );

INSERT INTO dbo.Movement
  VALUES ( 1, 1, '20110301', 2, NULL )  
    , ( 2, 1, '20110501', 1, NULL )  
    , ( 1, 1, '20110801', 1, NULL ) 
    , ( 2, 1, '20111001', 1, NULL ) 
    , ( 2, 1, '20120201', 1, 0.5 ); 


GO
```

**AND NOW QUERY**

```
USE tempdb;
GO
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT c.EmployeeId, c.Data, c.Value
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EmployeeId ORDER BY Data) AS [r]
    FROM dbo.EmployeeCost c
  ),
cteCost AS (
  SELECT ec.EmployeeId, ec.Data, ec.Value
    , ISNULL(DATEADD(DAY, -1, c.Data), '20991231') AS NextDate
    FROM cte ec
      LEFT JOIN cte c ON ec.EmployeeId = c.EmployeeId
        AND c.r = ec.r +1
  )
SELECT c.Id, c.Name
  , m.Data, d.Name, m.Time AS [Time], ec.Value AS [Cost per Hour], m.SpecialCost
  , m.Time * ISNULL(m.SpecialCost, ec.Value) AS [Employe Cost]
  FROM dbo.Customer c
    JOIN dbo.Movement m ON m.CustomerId = c.Id
    JOIN dbo.Employe d ON m.EmployeeId = d.Id
    JOIN cteCost ec 
      ON ec.EmployeeId = m.EmployeeId
        AND m.Data BETWEEN ec.Data AND ec.NextDate;
GO
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks

**EDIT: RESULT QUERY**

```
--<----------------
Id           Customer   Data       Employe   Time     Cost per hour  Total Cost

1           Cli1       2011-03-01   Mirko      2            1.0000              2.0000000000
1           Cli1       2011-05-01   Andrea     1            1.0000                  1.0000000000
1           Cli1       2011-08-01   Mirko      1            1.5000                  1.5000000000
1           Cli1       2011-10-01   Andrea     1            1.0000                 1.0000000000
1           Cli1       2012-01-15   Mirko      1            2.0000          
1           Cli1       2012-02-01   Andrea     1            1.3000        0.5000000000
```

Comment: I dont believe you can use CTE in EF. You can either create a View/Stored procedure, execute the sql query manually or first fetch the data to the local machine and use linq to objects.

Comment: I understand. If I delete from my query the cte value, can i convert it to linq to entities?

Comment: You can similate the query in a combination of EF/ and Linq to objects. However, the performance difference will be huge (EF doesnt support PARTITION BY for example so you have to do it manually). If you give us an abstract description of the result you want, then we can built an example based on that.

Comment: n this query I need to see the hourly cost of an employee by date.

An employee said he worked 2 hours and costs his employer $ 3 per hour. The total will be 6. I edit my post with the result of the query, so it is clearer

Comment: I have to go now, perhaps someone else can do the translation. Else i'll pick this up later today

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any parameter which needs to be passed to the CTE statement, so you can [create a view](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) and map it in the model.

Then you can access the view like any other table.

edit

```
create view dbo.vwEmployeeCosts as 

;WITH cte AS (
    ...
)
select *
   ...
from
```

Then map this view in your model, like you would do it with a table

Comment: I don't think I follow you. After you create the view, you can add it to the model. You don't need to convert this code to LINQ, since will be working with the view

Comment: Yes, but I do not really like to insert sql script in my application, I prefer to work with linq :D

Comment: The view is going to be created on server

Comment: Yes but what does? I can not understand

Comment: EF doesn't work with CTE, so you'll have to find a workaround

Comment: ok ef does'nt work with cte..But I can use an alternative route using LINQ in this scenario? Eventually what I posted a query, and I wonder if such a query can be done with linq